# Showing image inline with div properly for different sizes

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create the types of boxes below using CSS. Since im a newbie at CSS, my biggest concern is to create the header so the seperator line has a little gap before the heart image no matter what size the box is.

[image]

This is my attempt:

HTML:

```
<div class="block">
  <p><em>04-05</em></p>
  <img class="block_pic" src="..."/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
  border: solid red;
  width:250px;
  height:150px;
 }

p{
 border-bottom:solid black 2px;
 width:83%;
 margin:5px;
}

.block_pic {
  width:30px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 5.5%;
  right:86.5%;
}
```

(https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqwoPV). My approach was to add a `border-bottom` to the `<p>` with the timestamp and then place an image afterwards with `position:absolute` to make it appear at the end of the border by tuning the numbers of top and right. I was only able to do this successfully by changing the numbers over and over until it finally ended up in the right place. Is there a smart way to position the heart image instead of doing what I've done? This would be useful when you are trying to create responsive boxes of different sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place the image first (before the `p`element) and use `float: right` on it. And use `calc` for the `p` tags width as shown below:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MEYRVY

```css
.block {
  border: solid red;
  width:250px;
  height:150px;
 }

p{
 border-bottom:solid black 2px;
 width: calc(100% - 45px);
 margin:5px;
}

.block_pic {
  width:30px;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img class="block_pic" src="..."/>
  <p><em>04-05</em></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the calc function, this is really helpful :) thanks